# react router query parameters changed component will unmount

Tags: react-router

When query parameters changed, the same component will unmount and then mount.for example:
I have a url like `/admin` and also have a component called Admin. In Admin, there are some inputs for searching. I add a query parameters after `/admin` like `/admin?userId=123`.The componet's `componentDidMount` will excute again. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solve for this

Answer (score 1):

```
and setting likes this 
export default function (history, app) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/admin/settings/user' component={getComponent(User,app,userModel)} />
      <Route path='/admin/settings/user/:id' component={getComponent(UserEdit,app,userModel)} />
      <Route path='/admin/settings/role' component={getComponent(Role,app,roleModel)} />
      <Route path='/admin/settings/menu' component=
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

getComponent is a layload component.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Brazh  I  used v4 and the router likes this;

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={getComponent(Login,app,loginModel)}/>
        <Route path='/admin' render={ props => (
          <Layout>
            { settings(history, app) }
          </Layout>
        )}/>
        <Route path='/finance' render={ props => (
          <Layout>
            { finance(history, app) }
          </Layout>
        )}/>
</Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URL` interface to set query string values without unmount and mount your components:

```
const queryStringValue = 'bar'

const url = new URL(window.location.toString());
url.searchParams.set('foo', queryStringValue);
window.history.replaceState(null, '', url.toString());
```

Also, this solution won't add a new item in browser navigation stack